# How did Carl Creel heal from Obelisk by Hydra's brainwashing words?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In Agents of SHEILD season 2 episode 1, both SHIELD and HYDRA are after the original 0-8-4 known as obelisk/diviner. Carl Creel manages to take hold of Obelisk, but it infects his arm.

In episode 2, Sunil Bakshi meets Creel to retrieve the obelisk. However Creel demands that they cure him first. Then Bakshi starts chanting the hypnotizing words and Creel's arm magically heals. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### We don't know.

What is likely is that Creel could not control how the Diviner affected him without being calm and in control.

When Bakshi says the phrase that activates Creel's conditioning, it seems to calm him down.

As Bakshi says:

> Calm down, Mr. Creel, take a deep breath and clear your mind. Remember your training.